# Checking input and output dimensions of a DL model in a PB file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I work with several DL models, commonly provided as a TensorFlow PB file with no additional information.
I need to extract from the PB file the names and dimensions of the input and output layers. 
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Netron** software. It can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron). It is a tool for DL models visualization as below:

[image]